# NebulaGraph Database gives ERROR message when create tag uses default value

Tags: database, graph, nebula-graph

```
CREATE tag tag test object class (objectRelationCn string ,objectRelationEn string ,objectModelCode string ,nuClearReactorModelId string ,type int ,fatherModelCode string ,MD5code string, file receiving time string,original file creation time string,permission  string,fatherName string ,classKey string ,versionPolicy int ,instanceVersionPolicy int ,afterCureServiceId string ,);
```

The above statement can be executed normally, NebulaGraph studio v3.4.1, graph 3.2.0.
The following statement sets the default value for the attribute on the basis of the above, but reports a syntax error at the MD5 attribute position: -1004:SyntaxError: syntax error near `_1,MD5 s`

```
CREATE tag tag test object class (objectRelationCn string DEFAULT tag test object class , objectRelationEn string DEFAULT test_object_1, objectModelCode string DEFAULT WHCSDX1, nuClearReactorModelId string DEFAULT 609946853282156544, type int DEFAULT 0, fatherModelCode string DEFAULT 609946853282156544_1,MD5 string,  file receiving time string, original file creation time string, permission string, fatherName string DEFAULT individual object, classKey string DEFAULT , versionPolicy int DEFAULT 1, instanceVersionPolicy int DEFAULT 2, afterCureServiceId string DEFAULT , );
```

I have tried many times and checked the statement. I checked the character set, replaced the underscore ("`_`") character or the Chinese character "code" in the md5 position, but it also reported a grammatical error.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE tag p2( fatherModelCode string DEFAULT '609946853282156544_1',MD5 string,  );
```

Comment: It would be nice to [edit] to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem.